# How To Get Flowey Back?

Tags: undertale

I just recently completed a neutral run where I experimented seeing how the story would go on if I only killed certain characters (it was my second run, my first run was True Pacifist) and I ended up choosing to kill Flowey instead of letting him live.
I planned to start a Genocide run after resetting the game, but Flowey was gone when i did. Flowey is basically the base for each story in undertale (pacifist and genocide) so I know I can't progress any further without him being here. I really just want to start anew and, without Flowey, I dont think I can access True Resets anymore. It may be possible if I did a genocide route, but then I'd have to fight Sans, and that would take FOREVER.

Basically, I am wondering if I can erase all my progress somehow. I heard that True Resets don't erase everything entirely, so is there another way? Please respond, Undertale is the only game I have that's any fun and I don't want to have to buy another game.

Comment: "I know I can't progress any further without him being here" - bad assumption. Just keep going.

Comment: You can't do true pacifist your first run, unless you mean you did a neutral path and then true pacifist after a soft reset. Right? Trying clarify for my own purposes.

Comment: This is **not** a duplicate of the linked question.  This question is asking about recovering from something that can't be done in a Genocide run (as you never fight any form of Flowey in Genocide), the linked question is asking about recovering from a Genocide run.

Comment: You absolutely can do True Pacifist as your first run. It seems ChronoD is slightly confused about how to complete True Pacifist.

Comment: Bit of a necropost but I did true pacifist my first run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\` There should be a folder called "UNDERTALE". If you want to remove absolutely *everything*, delete that folder.

If you're playing on the Steam version, make sure you disable Steam Cloud for the game as well.

Comment: Thank you-  question: Will this disable saving?

Comment: Nope. Deleting the folder just removes the save data, and disabling the Steam Cloud for the game only prevents Steam from restoring it.

Comment: For anyone who doesn't have system files visible by default: `windows key` + `R` will open the run window, then entering `%APPDATA%` will open a folder below this and should help you get there.

Answer (score 7):

He's still there, but you do miss some of his dialogue, as indicated in another answer.  A True Reset isn't necessary to get him back, almost any reset will do - if Flowey survived your last run, he'll be at the beginning of your next one.  If you killed him last time, of course, he won't confront you at the beginning of the game, because

> he remembers your previous runs unless you do a True Reset, and is afraid to confront you because he can't Load his Savefile while you're around - and you freaking killed him!

Manipulating the save files is only necessary if you absolutely don't want to spend the time to complete the game again to get him back AND absolutely want to hear his dialogue early in the game.  In Genocide, it might be worth it, as before you leave the Ruins he has one of only three voice-acted lines in the game if you qualify for Genocide when you go to leave.

Answer (score 2):

You can still get any ending without Flowey being present, though you will miss any dialog he would have before the final encounter with him.

A True Reset will be sufficient to restore Flowey's presence in future playthroughs. However, erasing the save data (as mentioned in the other answer) would get the same results faster.

Answer (score 1):

It worked once I deleted the .ini file, and, since I'm on Mac, I thought this might be useful for others:

- Go to Finder. At the top you should see 'Go', click on that, and then click 'Go to folder'.
- Copy and paste `~/Library/Application Support/com.tobyfox.undertale/` to that window.
- Once there, you will find `undertale.ini`, so you can delete it.